# GPU Rendering Stopped Working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I was using GPU CUDA rendering with Cycles and it was working fine, but part way through the render it stopped working and I had to continue the render with the CPU. Now the "GPU Compute" option in the render menu us grayed out, and in the System menu in preferences there are no devices available under "Cycles Compute Device." Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Maybe your GPU can't handle your render requirment and Blender automatically disabled it.

Comment: I experience the same problem, used CUDA for many years, but recently after downloading 2.8 blender version Cuda stoped working in blender 2.79 too, reinstalling drivers  doesn't solve the problem..